# Cannot find symbol location of variable type Character

Tags: java, symbols

So I've been trying to make a text rpg game using java, I keep running into this error

```
Mage.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    teammate.setHealth( teammate.getHealth() + 25 );
                                ^
  symbol:   method getHealth()
  location: variable teammate of type Character
1 error
```

my code for this is

```
public int Heal(Character teammate){
    // Heals a target
    mana -= 20;
    teammate.setHealth( teammate.getHealth() + 25 );

    }
```

I've defined getHealth and setHealth in another class file. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Character is the ** java Character**  class or a costum class you made?

Answer (score 0):

Java thinks that **Сharacter** - is the base type **java.lang.Character**, which has no method getHealth().
Replace

```
public int Heal(Character teammate){
```

on

```
public int Heal(your.full.package.name.Character teammate) {
```